# EF6 Read Only properties causing invalid column name

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have a situation that is close to the articles written about preventing object properties from being updated but their solutions are always to use the *NotMapped* attribute to solve the problem but that won't work for me because I need the data retrieved when executing a stored procedure but I don't want it updated when saving the entity because it isn't actually a column in the table.

So my question is, is it possible to do the following?:

I have two tables similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [StatusTypes](
    [intStatusID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [vchStatusType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [intSortOrder] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblStatusTypes_x_intSortOrder]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblStatusTypes_x_IsDeleted]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [StatusColor] [nvarchar](7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblStatusTypes_x_StatusColor]  DEFAULT (''),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblStatusTypes_x] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [intStatusID] ASC
))

GO

CREATE TABLE [MyItems](
    [intMyItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemDescription] [nvarchar](2000),
    [StatusId] [int],
CONSTRAINT [PK_MyItems_x] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [intMyItemId] ASC
))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyItems]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_STATUS] FOREIGN KEY([StatusId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[StatusTypes] ([intStatusID])
GO
```

So in order to save from extra queries and lookups, when we are fetching this data we use a stored procedure that looks similar to this:

```
SELECT
    intMyItemId,
    ItemDescription,
    StatusId,
    vchStatusType as StatusType
FROM MyItems i
INNER JOIN StatusTypes s
    ON s.intStatusID = i.StatusId
```

and an Entity that looks like this:

```
[Table("MyItems")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    [Column("intMyItemId")]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    [Column("ItemDescription")]
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    public string ItemStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Now this works fine when the stored procedure is executing and we work with the objects. The problem is say I'm trying to load a new item and I create one in code.  Even if I don't fill in the ItemStatus field, or specifically set it as NotModified like so: `DbContext.Entry<Item>().Property("ItemStatus").IsModified = false`, etc. I always get a failure saying Invalid column.

So is it possible to have a property filled in by a stored procedure call but still have updates work when that field is not important, effectively ignoring the field ONLY on inserts and updates.

Comment: Sorry, it's not possible. Create and use a separate class for stored procedure result.

Comment: I started going down that road and I derived from Item and I believe that still gives me the problem unless I put NotMapped on the derived class, which is very, very odd.  I guess my only option would be to duplicate the entire class which is really poor programming.

Comment: Don't derive because you are entering EF inheritance system. Good or bad, creating and maintaining a separate class with duplicate primitive properties is indeed the only option.

Comment: did you try to use `Ignore` ?

Comment: @Hadi Using Ignore is the same as using NotMapped property attribute.  I just duplicated the class with the same properties and it works fine now.  The only problem now is code maintenance.